# Count number of ways to reach a score

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on a task where I have a number now I want to know how many ways to reach to this number using 2,3,6 using additions and I can use a number as many number of times as possible.

**1st Example:**

```
Given number is 6
There are 3 ways to reach to this number:
2 +2 + 2 = 2*3
3 + 3 = 3*2
6
```

**2nd Example:**

```
Given number is 5
There are 2 ways to reach to this number:
2+3
3+2 (order matters here)
```

I have come up with below code with help of [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-number-ways-reach-given-score-game/):

```
static int count(int n) {
    // table[i] will store count of solutions for
    // value i.
    int table[] = new int[n + 1], i;

    // Base case (If given value is 0)
    table[0] = 1;

    // One by one consider given 3
    // moves and update the table[]
    // values after the index greater
    // than or equal to the value of
    // the picked move
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        table[i] += table[i - 2];
    for (i = 3; i <= n; i++)
        table[i] += table[i - 3];
    for (i = 6; i <= n; i++)
        table[i] += table[i - 6];

    return table[n];
}
```

This code is working only for 1st example, but not working for 2nd example because the program is returning 1 instead of 2.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You said only using 2, 3 and 6, but the first example says `6 * 1` so you used a `1`, but you state this example is correct?

Comment: @Nexevis, basically 6* 1 is nothing but using 6 itself, so correct. Also 2*3 is nothing but 2+2+2, I will update my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: So basically you need to reach the number with only addition with those 3 numbers, but use the numbers as many times as you want?

Comment: Define "reach" a number. In your first example, ```(2^3)-2``` is another way to reach 6.

Comment: @Nexevis, yes only addition as many number of times, I'll update it

Comment: @MichaelBianconi, I have updated my question now.

Comment: @learner Can you also clarify what you mean by "not working", whats the difference between the two examples?  What is not working about the second one?  It would be easy to see if you had a "Current output" vs "Expected Output" for example.

Comment: @Nexevis, I have updated it now.

Comment: In the link you mentioned, it is clear from the examples proposed there that the order is not important. This is why the answer is1 for the second example that you propose in your own post

Comment: The examples you have provided are very simple. What is your expected output for `9`?

Comment: @Damien, yes what change we can do to this code to get correct output.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you miss combinations such as 2+6+2 (where a lesser number comes after a greater number), because you run (for example) `table[10] += table[10-2]` *before*  `table[8] += table[8-6]`, so the former doesn't take into account the result of the latter.

To fix that, change this:

```
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        table[i] += table[i - 2];
    for (i = 3; i <= n; i++)
        table[i] += table[i - 3];
    for (i = 6; i <= n; i++)
        table[i] += table[i - 6];
```

to this:

```
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (i >= 2) {
            table[i] += table[i - 2];
        }
        if (i >= 3) {
            table[i] += table[i - 3];
        }
        if (i >= 6) {
            table[i] += table[i - 6];
        }
    }
```

so that you handle e.g. `table[10]` only after you've fully processed e.g. `table[8]`.

Comment: Nice solution, one thing I missed, I thought he/she wants all the sequences as well. I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

**For input 0 or 1, result should be 0, because no way to reach the score using 2, 3 or 6.**

I consider all the `tiny` numbers `( <= 6 )` first and then find all other numbers with a straight loop (no more if statements).

The returned type is long just to handle large inputs.

```
  if (n == 0 || n == 1)
     return 0L;

  if (n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 4)
     return 1L;

  if (n == 5)
     return 2L;

  if (n == 6)
     return 3L;

  // Otherwise, n>6

  long[] table = new long[n + 1];
  table[0] = 1; // Base case
  table[1] = 0L; //
  table[2] = 1L; // 2
  table[3] = 1L; // 3
  table[4] = 1L; // 2+2
  table[5] = 2L; // 2+3, 3+2
  table[6] = 3L; // 2+2+2, 3+3, 6

  for (int i = 7; i <= n; i++)
     table[i] = table[i - 2] + table[i - 3] + table[i - 6];

  return table[n];
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question at all. The OP asked how to fix his/her code; this answer just provides completely different code.

Comment: @ruakh, I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You count the number of solutions, without taking into account the order of the elements.

For example, for `n = 5`, `2 + 3` count for one element only,`3 + 2`is considered as the same solution.

To get the result that you are looking for, you need two modifications:

1. Instead of counting the number of solutions, you have to memorize all the corresponding solutions. At this level, you don't need to take the order in consideration, just memorize the number of 2, 3, 6 corresponding to one solution. This allows you to keep the same program structure, basically the same efficient algorithm.
2. Then, for each particular solution `(x, y, z)`, where `x, y, z` are the multiplicities associated to 2, 3, 6, you have to evaluate the number of possibilities `N(x, y, z)` obtained by modifying the order of the elements.

The corresponding number of solutions is :

```
N(x, y, z) = C(s, x) * C(s-x, y) * C(s-x-z, z)
```

Where `s = x+y+z` and the `C(n, p)` are the binomial coefficients

Note that the last factor is equal to `C(z, z) = 1`.